# Typescript : Add an autoincrement id attribute of each object in array

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have this array of Object :

```
myArray = [
        {
            "edoId": "4010",
            "storeName": "ABBEVILLE"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "3650",
            "storeName": "AGEN"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "3298",
            "storeName": "AIX ALLEES PROVENCALES"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "3309",
            "storeName": "AIX JAS DE BOUFFAN"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "3313",
            "storeName": "AIX LA PIOLINE"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "2119",
            "storeName": "AIX LES BAINS"
        },
    ...
    ]
```

i want to an auto-incremntal **id** property for each object of my array , using forEach ( not looping with **myArray.length** )

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: `i want` sounds like you want us to do the work for you, instead of helping because you're stuck. What have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: so whats the problem? try `myArray = myArray.map((i, idx) => ({...i, id: idx}))`

Comment: when iterate array.forEach((item,index)) , you will get item and index , the index you can use it as an id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method as you want in your question:

```
myArray.forEach(function(item, index){
    item.id = index;
    // or do whatever you want using index
});
```

> `forEach()` executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays).
>   callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> 1. the element value
> 2. the element index
> 3. the array being traversed

```js
var myArray = [
        {
            "edoId": "4010",
            "storeName": "ABBEVILLE"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "3650",
            "storeName": "AGEN"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "3298",
            "storeName": "AIX ALLEES PROVENCALES"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "3309",
            "storeName": "AIX JAS DE BOUFFAN"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "3313",
            "storeName": "AIX LA PIOLINE"
        },
        {
            "edoId": "2119",
            "storeName": "AIX LES BAINS"
        }
    ];

myArray.forEach(function(item, index){
  item.id = index;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
myArray.map(i => ({edoId: ++i.edoId ,storeName: i.storeName }))
```

Comment: 1. That doesn't add an `id` property. 2. It increments `edoId` when it probably shouldn't. 3. There is no autoincrementing property, either. Not in the classical sense of a monotonous sequence that is generated from outside the data source. 4. This mutates the original source even though it also produces a copy.